# how to use Codebehind in asp.net website project using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, asyncfileupload

i am using this :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
Codefile="Admin1.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin1" %>
```

but one of my website feature is not working ( asyncfileupload ) in hosted server but its working in localhost ...

somehow i got the idea that its happening bcoz of i am using `codefile` instead of `codebehind` so my query is how can i use `codebehind` i have tried this :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Admin1.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin1" %>
```

but its give error saying can't load `admin1` so what to do now? how can i get my website working?

**UPDATE:-**

this my .cs file code

```
  public partial class admin1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   //all the codes
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio, are you using a `Website` project or a `Web Application` project?

Comment: @dbaseman: `website` project

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been a while since I've worked with website projects.  Drawing a blank :(

Comment: Can you display the code  `Admin1.aspx.cs`

Comment: @VeeKeyBee : i updated my QS pls check i added a piece of code

Comment: Inherits must be the full type name. Is admin1 in a specific namespace?

Comment: If you use a website project rather than a web application project, you must use `codefile` and not `codebehind`. The `codebehind` attribute is used for when the project is compiled into a DLL (which goes in the `bin` folder of your application). But this shouldn't be affecting your `asyncfileupload`.

Comment: i solved this problem ... my hosting server has permission issue in every folder so gave the permission and it worked

Comment: @ArindamDas What permission you modify. You should aware about the permissions

Comment: @VeeKeyBee : i modified that folders read/write permission